# Error when pmatrix/array is inside \ifcase

Tags: matrices

The following example produces an incomprehensible error:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{exam}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
 We are interested in the following matrix:
 \begin{gather*}
  \ifcase 0 \relax  
    C = \begin{pmatrix}  1 &  2 \\  1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}
  \or 
    C = \begin{pmatrix}  3 &  4 \\  1 & -5 \end{pmatrix} 
  \fi
 \end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

What is going on here? It works fine if I replace by the matrices by anything else, so I presume it is the interaction of the pmatrix environment with the ifcases.

The problem persists if pmatrix is replaced by the more foundational array.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{exam}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
 We are interested in the following matrix:
 \begin{gather*}
  \ifcase 0 \relax  
    C = \begin{array}{cc}  1 &  2 \\  1 & -2 \end{array}
  \or 
    C = \begin{array}{cc}  3 &  4 \\  1 & -5 \end{array} 
  \fi
 \end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The arrays would have to become `\begin{array}{cc}` or so but this is not essential.

Answer (score 5):

If you put braces, it works.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
 We are interested in the following matrix:
 \begin{gather*}
  \ifcase 0 \relax  
    { C = \begin{pmatrix}  1 &  2 \\  1 & -2 \end{pmatrix} }
  \or 
    { C = \begin{pmatrix}  3 &  4 \\  1 & -5 \end{pmatrix} }
  \fi
 \end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem are the `&`; you can solve it by bracing the entries, but there's a possibly better way:

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\docases}{mm}
 {
  \int_case:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\caseexam}{1}

We are interested in the following matrix:
\begin{gather*}
\docases{\caseexam}
 {
  {1}{C = \begin{pmatrix}  1 &  2 \\  1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}}
  {2}{C = \begin{pmatrix}  3 &  4 \\  1 & -5 \end{pmatrix}}
 }
\end{gather*}


\renewcommand{\caseexam}{2}

We are interested in the following matrix:
\begin{gather*}
\docases{\caseexam}
 {
  {1}{C = \begin{pmatrix}  1 &  2 \\  1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}}
  {2}{C = \begin{pmatrix}  3 &  4 \\  1 & -5 \end{pmatrix}}
 }
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Of course you'd set the `\caseexam` macro only once. Variations on the theme are possible.

[image]